# Prove that a classical solution of $-\langle\nabla,A\nabla u\rangle=f$ is also a weak one

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let

- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ a domain
- $f\in L^2(\Omega)$
- $A:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be Borel-measurable and $A(x)$ be symmetric, for all $x\in\Omega$
- $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ with $A\nabla u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ and $$-\langle\nabla,A\nabla u\rangle=f\;\;\;\text{in }\Omega\tag{1}$$

How can we show, that $$-\int_\Omega\langle A\nabla u,\nabla\varphi\rangle\;d\lambda^n=\int_\Omega f\varphi\;d\lambda^n\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_0^1(\Omega)\tag{2}\;?$$ Clearly, from $(1)$ we get $$-\int_\Omega\langle\nabla,A\nabla u\rangle\varphi\;d\lambda^n=\int_\Omega f\varphi\;d\lambda^n\;,$$ but I've no idea how we can show $$-\int_\Omega\langle\nabla,A\nabla u\rangle\varphi\;d\lambda^n=-\int_\Omega\langle A\nabla u,\nabla\varphi\rangle\;d\lambda^n$$ I assume we need to apply one of Green's identities, but how?

Comment: I've never seen the $\left\langle\nabla ,A\nabla u\right\rangle$ notation before - what does it mean?

Comment: @BaronMingus It's the formal scalarprodukt of $$\nabla=\left(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n\right)^T$$ and $A\nabla u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the vector form of integration by parts in higher dimensions:
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla\phi\cdot\boldsymbol{v}\,d\Omega= \int_{\partial\Omega}\phi(\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{n})\,d\Gamma-\int_{\Omega}\phi\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{v}\,d\Omega.$$
In your case, $\boldsymbol{v} = A\nabla u$ and equality (2) follows immediately, assuming the notation $\phi \in C_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ means that $\phi$ has compact support, i.e. vanishes on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with your notation, but maybe this can help you. Recall Green's identity for scalar fields $u$, $\phi$:

$$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot A \nabla u) \, \phi \, \mathrm{d} \Omega =  \int_{\partial \Omega} ( \mathbf{n} \cdot A \nabla u )\, \phi \, d\Gamma - \int_\Omega A \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \, \mathrm{d}\Omega,$$ where $\partial \Omega$ is the border of $\Omega$. I think your identity follows now if $\mathbf{n} \cdot A \nabla u = 0$ holds.

I have assumed that:

$$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot A \nabla u) \, \phi \, \mathrm{d} \Omega =  \int_\Omega \langle \nabla, A \nabla u\rangle \phi \, \mathrm{d} \Omega $$

Let me know if this was helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: How exactly did you use Green's (first?) identity? $A$ is a matrix-valued functions depending on $x\in\Omega$. So, we should need to consider derivatives of $A$, shouldn't we?

Comment: Did you made a mistake? It seems like you have treated $A$ as a constant matrix.

Comment: Hi @0xbadf00d, I'm not sure if this identity holds for a matrix-valued function $A$. If A is a scalar, I'm quite sure that my identity holds for every $u$ and $\phi$. It follows: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensIdentities.html